# UICollectionView reloadData issue - cell's subview issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have maked following view.

[image]

But when calling `-reloadData`, the view becomes...

[image]

I think it's because cells is reused.
Do you have any idea to keep view as first image even if calling `reloadData`?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        cell.label.text = @"Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = dataArray[indexPath.item];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

CustomCell.m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* label;

//...

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {        
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgViewFrame];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

        self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT:

I modified my code.
 - setting all default values before setting them with correct data
 - calling -prepareForReuse
When calling `-reloadData`, Although `imageView.image` stay nil, `label.text` in indexPath.item==0 becomes nil and `label.text` in indexPath.item==3 outputs @"Hello".

Comment: i think is because of reusableCell.. dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Comment: Before setting text and image on label and imageview
set it to 
cell.label.text = @"";
cell.imageview.image = nil;

Then set what you want to set

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its because of reusability. You can avoid it by changing line of code to this:

```
if (indexPath.item == 0)
{
    cell.label.text = @"Hello";
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
else
{
    UIImage *image = dataArray[indexPath.item];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.label.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're retrieving the dequeued cells they are already setup. So the first time you retrieve 9 different cells and initialise them accordingly.
The second time tough the cells properties are already set so you need to restart them.
So your code should look as follows:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.label.text = @"Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = dataArray[indexPath.item];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.label.text = nil;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is the outcome the same after you modify your code?

Comment: When calling -reloadData, Although imageView.image stay nil, label.text in indexPath.item==0 becomes nil and label.text in indexPath.item==3 outputs @"Hello".

Comment: it should not be indexPath.item, but indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all default values of your cell before doing any check:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Set all default values before setting them with correct data
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.label.text = @"";

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.label.text = @"Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = dataArray[indexPath.item];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

You could add this method to your CustomCell.m

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    //Set default values here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

REPORT: 
I solved the issue on my own.so, I will report it.
I used the property `hidden`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        cell.label.text = @"Hello";

        cell.imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = dataArray[indexPath.item];
        cell.imageView.image = image;

        cell.label.hidden = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This looks incomplete. You should set your hidden properties default to NO before doing any other things